# Vue2: The right way to include / inject a global utility class

Tags: dependency-injection, vuejs2

I have Vue.js project where I would like to use a utility class for functions I want to use in all my modules.

modules/Utils.js

```
export default class Utils {
    array_count (arr) {
        return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.length : 0;
    }
}
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Utils from 'modules/Utils';
export default new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {
        App
    },
    utils: Utils // this has no affect?
```

});

modules/some.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Utils from 'modules/Utils'; // I don't want this
var utils = new Utils;             // I don't want this
console.log(utils.array_count(['a','b','c']));
```

I don't really understand how to inject the Utils Class. The example above works - but I would like to get rid of the import of the Class in each module. I thought when I add it in main.js as a dependency, I should be able to call it anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to access the helpers from every component you could register a global mixin.
Change your `Utils.js` to look like a [Mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

```
export default {
    methods: {
        array_count (arr) {
            return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.length : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, import the mixin and add it globally.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Utils from 'modules/Utils';
Vue.mixin(Utils);
export default new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {
        App
    },
```

Alternatively, if you want some helper functions not to be available globally but just in some components, you could import the mixin and add it manually to Vue components.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use plugin instead of mixin according to Vue documentation:

Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, including third party components. In most cases, you should only use it for custom option handling like demonstrated in the example above. It’s also a good idea to ship them as Plugins to avoid duplicate application.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear - I am already using mixins - but my helper class should be available to other classes as well - not only to *.vue components.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible since you want to use it in .js file without importing it. If you have multiple modules which you want to share between files, maybe the best option is to create one single file import all modules which you want to share and then you have only one import instead of repeating.

Comment: Is it really not possible to extend Vue? Like Vue.Utils.myMethod() ? Maybe something like a factory?

Comment: Plugins look good to me! I can add Vue.myMethod() with a plugin. Can I also add Vue.Utils.myMethod() ?

Comment: You could put the class in the Vue prototype? https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html